# Can't get two shapefiles to plot together

Tags: coordinate-system, r

I have two shapefiles that I am trying to plot in R together with no luck.  I believe both shapefiles have the same projection based on the following information:

Shapefile 1 - sams

```
proj4string(sams)
[1] "+init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
```

Shapefile 2 - y_17s

```
proj4string(y_17s)
[1] "+init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
```

Both shapefiles have similar bounding boxes:

```
sams@bbox
        min       max
x -68.49947 -66.33404
y  40.39582  41.50014


  y_17s@bbox

                  min       max
    beglong -67.33030 -66.37333
    beglat   40.62744  41.49482
```

But when I plot the sams shapefile and use degAxis to label the axis the values for longitude are displayed like 499640 E

while the y_17s longitude axis is displayed like 68 W

To me this makes me think the projections for both shapefiles are no the same even though they look like they are.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: can you try `t(apply(coordinates(sams), 2, range))` and the same for `y_17s` - just check that the bbox do correspond to the coordinates under the hood more or less, but also what is the actual range of the plot - use `axis(1); axis(2)` to get it without degAxis, or `par("usr")` to get the numbers

Comment: If you can edit and add the code you used to make the plot, and include the plot image that would be great.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions.  I ended up changing the projection of the sams shapefile in Arc Map and now both shapefiles are plotting together in R.